# Change Hue or Color of a PNG with ASP.Net/VB.Net/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, xhtml

I'm working on a web page that takes multiple PNG images and merges them into one image so the user can download the flat image. I would like to add a hue or color adjustment (like color balance in photoshop) so I can adjust the different PNG image layers without having to create a separate image for each hue. Right now I'm using ASP.net/VB.net and some jQuery and the System.Drawing.Image method to merge the images. I can't seem to find any information on doing this for the web without using silverlight or flash and I do not want to use either. If anyone could link me to a tutorial or provide some basic code to get me in the right direction it would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It will take you a lot of code to reinvent the wheel, just go with imagemagick or graphicsmagick.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick ;) http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#dot-net